# How can i fix this jquery script for submenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

This is the code and this is the result: you can see test the menu by clicking inside.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $links = $('#menu-menu-1 .menu-item a').click(function () {



        var submenu = $(this).next();
        $subs.not(submenu).hide()
        submenu.toggle(500);
        $("#menu-2").slideToggle(300);
    });
    var $subs = $links.next(); });
```

The problem is that if I click on the menu it appears the submenu, but if I don't close the submenu that I have open and I open another voice in the menu it doesn't work properly.

If I click another `.menu-item a` when #menu-2 is open what happens? The script close and open another submenu correctly but my `#menu-2` close only close. And then if I close `.menu-item a` so... `#menu-2` open. How can I do to fix?

Comment: can you share the relevant html

Comment: you can see the source here: www.studionews24.com and you can test the menu.the html code is generated by php. Is dynamic. If you need i can write the css style for #menu-2 ecc ecc...

Comment: The problem is because of the line `$("#menu-2").slideToggle(300)`

Comment: Ok but i need it for show the submenu. #menu-2 is the grey navbar that is hidden at the first. If i remove it it doesn't work for my porpouse.

Comment: I have pasted it but i think doesn't work. Can you see from source if is correct as i have pasted it?

Comment: there was an error in the code... the below answer has fixed it... can you try that

Comment: Ok i try the code above thanks.

Comment: it seems to be working now, isn't it?

Comment: Ok but is the same if i replace slideToggle from original code with slideDown. It work as the same..is not possible to have slide effect of #menu-2 at the change of submenu category? Because with this code it remains like this.

Comment: @GiulioBambini try the updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $menu2 = $("#menu-2");
    var $links = $('#menu-menu-1 .menu-item a').click(function () {
        var submenu = $(this).next();
        $subs.not(submenu).hide();
        var isVisible = submenu.stop(true, true).is(':visible');
        $menu2.stop(true, true);
        if (isVisible) {
            submenu.hide(500);
            $menu2.slideUp(300);
        } else {
            $menu2.slideUp(300, function () {
                $menu2.slideDown(300);
                submenu.show(500);
            });
        }
    });
    var $subs = $links.next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify what you're trying to do with something along these lines (untested):

```
$(function () { 
    var menuItems = $('#menu-menu-1 > li');
    var submenus = $('ul', menuItems)

    menuItems.click(function () {

        submenus.slideUp(); // Hide all menus to their default hidden state
        var submenu = $('ul', $(this)); // Show the child menu for the clicked menu
        submenu.toggle(500);
    });
});
```